# How to filter single value from an rxjs stream to print in angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have these two rxjs stream in an Angular 2 component. One list contains speakers and the other list contains languages. Each speaker has a foreign key of a language found in languages list.

```
 speakers: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
 languages: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
```

Now I want to print language name against each speaker in `*ngFor`, or let me give you an angular expression of what things I want to print for each speaker html tag.

`<p>{{speaker.Name}} , {{speaker.Language_Id}}, {{speaker.getLanguage()}}, {{getLanguage(speaker.Language_Id)}}</p>`.

I am using `speaker.getLanguage()` and `getLanguage(speaker.Language_Id)` to know which one is better and are both possible?

I have not defined types on the client side in TypeScript code. Will I need to?

I have tried creating a function in component but it says `find` doesn't exist on type FirebaseListObservable. This is how simple it was in plane javascript :-P.

```
getLanguage(languageId: number):string{
  return this.languages.find(x=>x.Id==languageId).
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is it supposed to know that languageId is a property of any[]?

I would suspect you may need typing in this case, however I wouldn't attribute that to your current problem.

To address the find function issue, have a look at the documentation [here](https://angularfire2.com/api/classes/_utils_firebase_list_observable_.firebaselistobservable.html).

There is no find listed under this type according to the documentation, you may need to convert it to an array using the **toArray** method provided.

This array should then have the find functionality you are after: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find